# Is attr_accessible inherited by derived classes whe using STI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a class structure similar to this for a family of classes using STI

```
class Root < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :root_prop
end

class Child < Root
  attr_accessible :child_prop
end

class Grandchild < Child
  attr_accessible :gc_prop
end
```

All my properties were working fine until I added the attr_accesible markers, so I know it is related to that.  Now it appears that the properties giving accessible status on the base classes are not getting set.  Does attr_accessible need to be set completely for each class, or do I need to look somewhere else for the reason for the values not getting set?

Comment: If you want to post this as an answer, I'll write up my actual issue as a comment on your answer.  I don't really want to answer my own question since you did point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment here is the answer.  The attr_accessible method does work for derived classes.  However, when dealing with associations, the accessible attribute requires the _id suffix

```
class Grandchild < Child
  attr_accessible :associated_class_id
  belongs_to :associated_class
end
```

Is the correct way to mark an association with the attr_accessible method.  This detail was missing from the original question.